# Looks like you forgot to register the http module with Windsor Castle with IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, castle-windsor

I am using windsor DI framework in one of my MVC project. The project works fine when I tried to run from Visual Studio 2008.

But when i tried to run the project creating an application in IIS7 then I recieved the following error message:

> Looks like you forgot to register the http module
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule Add '<add
>   name="PerRequestLifestyle"
>   type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule,
>   Castle.MicroKernel" />' to the  section on your
>   web.config

But this module already exists in the httpmodule section of web.config file.

Does anyone know what I have to do to eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try adding it to the `system.webServer` section as well?

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="..." />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="..." />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <configuration><br/>
        <system.web><br/>
            <httpModules><br/>
                <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="..." /><br/>
            </httpModules><br/>
        </system.web><br/>
        <system.webServer><br/>
            <modules><br/>
                <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="..." /><br/>
            </modules><br/>
        </system.webServer><br/>
    </configuration><br/> ...  for me.

Comment: <modules> should be corrected as <httpModules> under <system.web>.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same error, but it caused by another reason:

I tried to resolve `IService` at `Application_Start` for custom route class processing, but type for `IService` was registered with `PerWebRequestLifestyle`. Routing subsystem stays at higher level that web request, and objects not exist at route processing time.

Comment: Very big +1. I, too, was trying to juggle PerWebRequest Lifestyles in my Application_Start and it was causing false positives on this error.

Comment: Same here. Moving registration into BeginRequest solved it in my case.

Comment: Rather than move to BeginRequest I created a hybrid lifecycle to use transient when the HtttpContext.Request is null.

Comment: @Cookie Could you please explain what you did? Sounds like greek to me, but i feel that is where the solution for my issue is..

Comment: Basically create a new lifestyle for castle, inherit from IScopeAccessor   then have a method GetScope(CreationContext){return HttpContext.Current == null ? this.perWebRequestScopeAccessor.GetScope(context) : this.transientScopeAccessor.GetScope(context);} Then when you register the assembly choose the new lifestyle.

Answer (score 4):

It helped me:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've come across this issue in my dev enviroment. What's worth noting is this tag:

```
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

While it obviously does what it says on the tin, it can stop those pesky errors showing up. Assuming the rest of your configuration is working Ok.

What has worked for me:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="PerRequestLifestyle"/>
    <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post that explains the issue in a code-level by decompiling the Castle.Windsor.dll.

[Fixed and Explained: Forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule](https://sitecorelogy.com/2016/05/25/fixed-sitecore-forgot-to-register-the-http-module-castle-microkernel-lifestyle-perwebrequestlifestylemodule/)

Comment: This is a dead link.