# IIS7 & Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule registering problems

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config, castle-windsor

**UPDATE:**

In Windsor 2.5 the assembly name is `Castle.Windsor` not `Castle.MicroKernel`

---

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC app to IIS7 and I'm getting this error:

> Looks like you forgot to register the http module
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule Add '' to the  section on your
>   web.config

My httpModules contains:

```
<httpModules>
   <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.MicroKernel"/>
</httpModules>
```

system.webServer handlers section contains

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="PerRequestLifestyle"/>
  <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Microkernel" verb="*" path="*.castle" />
</handlers>
```

I added the `verb="*" path="*.castle"` part as I was getting errors when they were missing. Not sure if their values are correct.

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: PerWebRequestLifestyleModule is a module, not a handler. Remove it from the handlers section.

Comment: Try including the Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken in the module declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the module declaration. The Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken weren't necessary.
I also had to add
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

as a handler.

Also had to create the directory 'C:\TempImageFiles' to get it working.

Comment: So did it solve your problem? And what does ChartImageHandler have to do with Windsor?

Comment: Heh heh. Looks like I confused myself there. I was having problems with both Castle and ChartImageHandler - looks like I thought I had asked about ChartImageHandler in my question when I commented. 

Anywhoo - yes, my problem is solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looks like you forgot to register the http module with Windsor Castle with IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258011/looks-like-you-forgot-to-register-the-http-module-with-windsor-castle-with-iis7)

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the problem by registering the HTTP module in **configuration/system.webServer/modules** instead of **configuration/system.web/httpModules**.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I was bootstraping the container in `Application_Start`, Modules are not initialized at that point in ASP.NET so when you try to register/use `PerWebRequest` Lifestyle it throws that Exception because it detects that the module was not initialized.

I ended up using [this library](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/Castle.Windsor.Lifestyles) from [Castle Contrib](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib/) which provides the `HybridPerWebRequestTransient` Lifestyle which if not initialized at the moment uses the Transient Lifestyle.

You just have to download the library (as zip is ok) open the Solution and compile it, grab the generated DLL and reference it in your project.

If you are using Castle.Windsor version over 3.0 you will have to remove current reference to it and add the reference to the version you are using (I was using 3.1 and did not have any problems).

This is the code to use the Lifestyle: `.LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient()`

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to find a solution for this but all I had to was update the dll being referneced in the web.config...

Using Castle.Core and Windsor 2.5.1...