# castle PerRequestLifestyle not recognize

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, perwebrequest

New to Castle/Windsor, please bear with me.

I am currently using the framework [System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/01/25/just-released-system-web-mvc-extensibility-beta.aspx) and in its start up code, it registered HttpContextBase like the following:

```
container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>().LifeStyle.Transient.UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

What I wanted to do is to change the behavior and change the lifestyle of httpContextBase to be PerWebRequest.

so I have change the code to the following:

```
container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>().LifeStyle.PerWebRequest.UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

However, when I do this, I got the following error:

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Looks like you forgot to 
 register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule
 Add '<add name="PerRequestLifestyle" 
 type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.MicroKernel" 
 />' to the <httpModules> section on your web.config
```

which I did under `<system.web>` and `<system.webServer>`, however, I am still getting the same error.  Any hints?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

added code block per request

In the system.web.mvc.extensibility framework, there is a class called extendedMvcApplication which inherit from HttpApplication, and in the Application_start method, it calls BootStrapper.Execute().  This implementation of this method is the following:

```
public void Execute()
    {
        bool shouldSkip = false;

        foreach (IBootstrapperTask task in ServiceLocator.GetAllInstances<IBootstrapperTask>().OrderBy(task => task.Order))
        {
            if (shouldSkip)
            {
                shouldSkip = false;
                continue;
            }

            TaskContinuation continuation = task.Execute(ServiceLocator);

            if (continuation == TaskContinuation.Break)
            {
                break;
            }

            shouldSkip = continuation == TaskContinuation.Skip;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it loops through a list of IBootStrapperTask and tries to execute them.  It so happens that I have one task that register the routes in my mvc app:

```
public class RegisterRoutes : RegisterRoutesBase
{
    private HttpContextBase contextBase;

    protected override TaskContinuation ExecuteCore(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        contextBase = serviceLocator.GetInstance<HttpContextBase>();
        return base.ExecuteCore(serviceLocator);
    }

    protected override void Register(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new { robotstxt = @"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?" });

        XmlRouting.SetAppRoutes(routes, contextBase.Server.MapPath("~/Configuration/Routes.xml"));
    }
}
```

you can see that I need to getInstance(resolve) a httpcontextbase object such that I can get the server path of a xml file.

Comment: when do you resolve that object? at which point?

Comment: on Application_Start(), is that too early?

Comment: @Herman: it's not supported right now. What are you trying to Resolve in Application_Start()?

Comment: @Mauricio: in the system.web.mvc.extensibility framework, it allows you to wire up a bunch of tasks up-front.  One of the task that I implemented is wiring up all the routes values which depends on httpcontext to look up a server path to a xml file.  My workaround for now is to use tranisent instead of perwebrequest, which works for my scenario.

Comment: @Herman: ok, but why do you Resolve() that in Application_Start()? can you post some of that code?

Comment: @Herman: added a couple of workaround to my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of this writing, PerWebRequest lifestyle does not support resolving in Application_Start().

See issue description and discussion:

- http://support.castleproject.org/projects/IOC/issues/view/IOC-ISSUE-166
- http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/d44d96f4b548611e

Workarounds for this particular case:

1. Register `RegisterRoutes` as an instance, explicitly passing it the current context as constructor parameter, e.g.:

   ```
   container.Register(Component.For<IBootstrapperTask>()
                               .Instance(new RegisterRoutes(Context)));
   ```
2. Use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` instead of `contextBase.Server.MapPath`. Want to make it mockable? Use it through a simple interface, e.g.:

   ```
   interface IServerMapPath {
       string MapPath(string virtualPath);
   }

   class ServerMapPath: IServerMapPath {
       public string MapPath(string virtualPath) {
           return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath);
       }
   }

   container.AddComponent<IServerMapPath, ServerMapPath>();
   ```

Then inject `IServerMapPath` into your `RegisterRoutes`.

Answer (score 0):

Maby try to add it under Modules section, like here:
[IIS7 & Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule registering problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498722/iis7-castle-microkernal-lifestyle-perwebrequestlifestylemodule-regestering-prob)

http://www.jasonlinham.co.uk/2009/02/castle-and-iis7.html