# Windsor PerWebRequest resolution in Application_Start

Tags: castle-windsor, perwebrequest

I am injecting HttpContextBase into a caching class. HttpContextBase is registered as PerWebRequest. I interact with the caching class on each web request and this works fine, but I also need to initialise the cache at application start.

I understand that PerWebRequest does not work in Application_Start though:

[castle PerRequestLifestyle not recognize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670717/castle-perrequestlifestyle-not-recognize)

What is the best way to resolve this in my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not use stuff that depends on per-web-request stuff outside of web request.

If you need to depend on a class you registered as PWR I'd suggest getting another component for that service with different lifestyle and using it in Application_Start and using `IHandlerSelector` to return PWR one when you're within a web request, and the other one otherwise

Comment: it is not unreasonable to want to pre-populate a cache on application start, so what options do I have if I want to use Windsor to resolve the caching class which depends on HttpContextBase?

Comment: How can you use HttpContextBase outside of web request?

Comment: You still have an HttpContext in the Application_Start event

Comment: Updated the answer with _workaround_. I'd still try to restructure your code not to rely on something you chose to bind to web requests outside of web requests.

Comment: +1 Krzysztof's workaround is correct. Use a transient for Application_Start()

Answer (score 4):

Try using an [hybrid webrequest/transient lifestyle](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/06/hybrid-lifestyles-in-windsor.html).

Comment: althought I still say - refactor should be your first option

Comment: @mauricio-scheffer I'm a bit confused, let's say I register IDBcontext with hybrid webrequest in my applicaiton_start, now when the app starts there is no httpcontext, so it will be registered as tansient. So how will IDBcontext ever be registered as perrequest lifestyle?

Comment: @Arvand if there is a HttpContext the container will try to resolve it from the context. Otherwise it will create a fresh instance.

Answer (score 0):

To warmup caches when the container starts I usually use the Startable Facility.
Here is an example on how to use it: 
http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,a621ddda-acb5-4afd-84ff-faafb96a2fa1.aspx

Comment: it will still eagerly instantiate the service